# Is it possible to do cache busting with HTTP/2?

Tags: caching, http2

Has anybody tried?

Here is the use case. In a first request-response cycle, this would happen:

Request 1:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
...
```

Response 1

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Etag: version1
Cache-control: max-age=1

... angly html here
....<link href="mycss.css" >
...
```

Request 2:

```
GET /mycss.css HTTP/1.1
...
```

Response 2 (probably pushed):

```
Etag: version1
Cache-control: max-age=<duration-of-the-universe>

...
... brackety css ...
...
```

and then, when the browsers goes a second time to the same page, it will of course fetch again the "/" resource because of the very short max-age:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
...
If-not-modified: version1
```

But it won't  fetch mycss.css if it has it in cache. However, the server can use the validator present in the "if-not-modified" header of the request for "/" to get an idea of the client's cache age, and may conclude that mycss.css version's of the browser is too old. In that case, before even answering the previous request, the server can ["promise"](http://http2.github.io/http2-spec/index.html#PushResources) a new version of  mycss.css/

By the specs, should the browser accept and use it?

Answer (score 2):

## Overview:

I still don't know what the answer to my question is from a purely theoretical side, but at least today it doesn't seem possible in practice to do cache-busting this way :-(, with neither Google Chrome or Firefox. Both reject or ignore the pushed stream if they believe that the resource they have in cache is fresh.

I also got this from somebody who prefers to remain anonymous:

> Browsers will typically put resources received through push in a 
>   "demilitarized zone" and only once the client asks for that resource
>   it will  be moved into the actual cache.  So just pushing random
>   things will not make  them end up in the browser cache even if the
>   browser accepts them at the push  moment.

## Update

As early 2016, it is still not possible, due mainly to lack of consensus on how this should be handled, and if it should be allowed at all or not. 
As [this page shows](https://www.shimmercat.com/en/info/articles/caching/#url-query-parameters-are-still-needed-to-update-assets-at-clients-), even with HTTP/2, the way to solve the stale assets issue is to create a unique URL for each asset version, and then ensure that the user receives that new URL when they re-visit the page.